# Parse Json Request from CURL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to parse Json data from curl request.Need to split  Mac,Parameter,datatype,value from below curl request and pass those data's as input for set method(For each Mac separately).Can anyone please guide how to split?

```
curl  -k -s -H  "Content-Type: application/json"   -d  '{"Data": {"Mac":"10.43.33.34","Parameter":"Device.wifi","datatype":"string","value":"5Ghz"},{"Mac":"15.23.43.48","Parameter":"Device.wifi","datatype":"string","value":"2.4GHZ"}}'  http://test:3000/api/executions_api_set/
```

Set API

```
  def show
       
        client = SetClient.new
        versionResponse = client.set_req(mac,parameter,datatype,value)
        if versionResponse.code == "200"
          value = JSON.parse(versionResponse.body)
          render json: {Mac: mac,Response:value}, status: :ok
        else
          render json: {Mac: mac,Parameter: parameter,status: 'Failed',responsecode:versionResponse.code}, status: :ok

        end

     end
    end
  end


end
```

Updated Code

```
def create
        value = ''
        client = SetClient.new
        params["Data"].each do |mac_attributes|
          @mac_address, @Parameter, @dataType, @value = mac_attributes.values_at("Mac", "Parameter", "datatype", "value")
          @versionResponse = client.set_req_api(@mac_address,@Parameter,@dataType,@value)
          puts "versionResponse.status_code #{@versionResponse.code}"
       
         end
        if @versionResponse.code == "200"
          value = JSON.parse(@versionResponse.body)
          render json: {Mac_address: @mac_address,Response:value}, status: :ok
          else
          render json: {Mac_address: @mac_address,Parameter:@Parameter,status: 'Failed',responsecode:@versionResponse.code}, status: :ok
        end  
     
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. I believe your CURL request has malformed JSON content, you're needing to wrap the list of mac address JSON objects in an array. Something like `{"Data": [{"Mac":"..."},{}]}`. Rails will then parse the JSON body content and give you an array of hashes with the keys and values from your JSON object. e.g. `params["Data"]` is an array of objects, `params["Data"].map{|mac_object| mac_object["Mac"]}` would be the array of mac addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but if you want the controller to call a method for each JSON object in the array, it would look something like:

```rb
def show
  params["Data"].each do |hash_of_mac_attributes|
    mac, parameter, datatype, value = hash_of_mac_attributes.values_at("Mac", "Parameter", "datatype", "value")
    method_you_want_to_call(mac, parameter, datatype, value)
  end
```

This is assuming that rails is correctly detecting and parsing the JSON body into the params hash for you. If it's not, that's a separate issue that can be addressed.

### UPDATE

In order to return the result from each call to the external service we need to store each call in an array and render the array in the response. Something like the following:

```rb
def show
  json_array = params["Data"].map do |hash_of_mac_attributes|
    mac, parameter, datatype, value = hash_of_mac_attributes.values_at("Mac", "Parameter", "datatype", "value")
    response = client.set_req_api(mac, parameter, datatype, value)
    build_json_for_mac_lookup(response: response, mac: mac, parameter: parameter)
  end

  render json: json_array
end
def build_json_for_mac_lookup(arguments:, mac:, parameter:)
  json_body = {Mac_address: mac}
  if response.code == "200"
    json_body.merge(Response: JSON.parse(response.body))
  else
    json_body.merge(Parameter: parameter, status: 'Failed', responsecode: response.code)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks.It  is Working.But I am getting redder error "AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".):

Comment: I have change show to create.If try to execute with show I am getting error "AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'create' could not be found for Api::V1::ExecutionsSetController):

Comment: Melcher- I have updated the code which working and getting only one  response for Mac which is executing last.How to get all response for all Mac execution?

Comment: {"Mac_address":"10.X.X.X","Response":{"parameters":[{"name":"Device.Wifi","message":"Success"}],"statusCode":200}}

Comment: Above response I am getting If I executing for More Mac address

Comment: An API can only return a single response to a request - but we can combine the results and return them as an array. I'll update my comment with some pesudo-code

Comment: Melcher I am facing one more issue.From my local It is working fine.Same code Prod It is not working.I am getting error "A JSON text must at least contain two octets!"  and response 403. I didn't understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: local api I am trying with http and In Production I am trying with https.Will it be any cause?. Same code It is working without any issues in my local.

Comment: That error (JSON text must contain at least two octets) mean's the thing you're parsing probably isn't JSON, and is probably empty. It's difficult to guess why - but any differences between dev and prod would be a good place to start. Could be HTTPS if it's an invalid certificate, but would need more info. Probably worth opening a new ticket explaining more about the problem.